# Spartacus - Is applying LAZY LOADING OF CMS COMPONENTS is correct when having many custom CMS components?

Tags: spartacus-storefront

My Storefront application have more than 50 custom CMS components.

SSR build creates separate JS files for each CMS component when applying **LAZY LOADING OF CMS COMPONENTS** approach.

Does it won't create any performance impact?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, using lazy loading of modules is recommended over lazy loading of components.

Historically, components lazy loading mechanism was created at a time where lazy loading of modules was not yet available.
But now lazy loading of modules is the preferred way to go.